# retrieve more than one field from SQLite database and compare with these field

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i want compare user name and password from database if exists than it success if not than throws error  i use **SQLiteOpenHelper** to don a task 
i can get one field from database now how can i retrieve multiple fields

```
 public UserInfo get_user_by_id(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        UserInfo userInfo = null;

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_APP_ID}, COLUMN_APP_ID + "=?", new String[]{id + ""}, null, null, null);

           while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
               //userInfo.setAppId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_APP_ID)));
               userInfo = new UserInfo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_APP_ID)));
           }
```

Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: search tutorial on google. This site is only give you answer if you struck anywhere in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a list of UserInfo from your method get_user_by_id().

```
public ArrayList<UserInfo> get_user_by_id(String id) {
    ArrayList<UserInfo> listUserInfo = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_APP_ID}, COLUMN_APP_ID + "=?", new String[]{id + ""}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
          UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
          userInfo.setAppId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_APP_ID)));
          // HERE YOU CAN MULTIPLE RECORD AND ADD TO LIST 
          listUserInfo.add(userInfo);
        }
    }
 return listUserInfo;
}
```

Comment: @Jatin: Welcome... Please accept the the answer by clicking on tick mark. If this is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLite Query like this ....

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username=username_value & password=password_value";

Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        // success
    }else{
   //   fail
}
```

Comment: You'd better select only the fields you need: `SELECT Field1, Field2, ... FROM TableName ...`